# Jquery ui dialog ok function not reloading the page

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I need to reload page when user clicks on 'OK' button on jquery UI dialog. I m trying the following but it does not seem work. The modal dialog does close though.

```
function ShowConfirmationDialogForNewSite() {
  $("#dialog").dialog({
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
        Ok: function () {
            window.location.reload(true);
            $(this).dialog("close");
            }              
        }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your dialog use the [**`close`**](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#method-close) property to reload:

```
function ShowConfirmationDialogForNewSite() {
    $("#dialog").dialog({
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            Ok: function () {            
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }              
        },
        close: function(event, ui){ 
            window.location.reload(true); 
        }
    });
}
```